# How to insert multiple checkbox value respect their id

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I fetch some value from database. and want to update the database table respect their ids.

here is my code:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ads ORDER BY ads_id DESC LIMIT $START, $LIMIT";
$result = mysql_query( $sql );
$num = mysql_num_rows( $result );
if( $num > 0 ){
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){ ?>
<tr bgcolor="#E1E1E1">
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" class="BlackText2">
    <?php echo $row['title'];?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" class="BlackText2">
    <?php echo substr($row['description'], 0, 40);?>
  </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
    <?php echo $row['mywebsite'];?>
  </td>
  <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
    <input type="hidden" name="ads_id[]" value="<?php echo $row['ads_id'];?>">
    <input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="feature">
  </td>
<?php
    if( isset( $_REQUEST['submit'] ) ){
      $feature = $_POST['feature'];
      $ads_id = $_REQUEST['ads_id'];
      if( empty( $feature ) ){
        echo( "You didn't select any buildings." );
      }else{
        $N = count( $feature );
        $M = count( $ads_id );
        echo("You selected $N door(s): ");
        for( $i=0 ; $i < $N ; $i++ ){
          for( $j=0 ; $j < $M ; $j++ ){
            echo ( $feature[$i] . " " );
            echo $update_feature = "UPDATE tbl_ads SET `featureads` = '".$feature[$i]."' WHERE ads_id ='".$ads_id[$j]."'";
            $result_feaure = mysql_query($update_feature);
          }
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

but my problem is when I update the featureads column respect ads_id column then all column are selected.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use `bgcolor` or `align` attributes, instead use CSS to style your output. And I would advise against using the `mysql_` functions, preferably use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or at least [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Also, where do the $START and $END variables come from? Few other problems with your code...

Comment: @Cobby thanks for suggestion, $START and $END variable comes from other sql. actually my problem is when I check 1 or 2 check box and the "$update_feature" sql run all featureads rows are update instead of that 2 selected fields

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a table that stores all of the ID's of something and you want someone to be able to define each record to be a featured "ad" and do it all at once.

My suggestion would be to change the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="feature">
```

To reflect the selected feature and backtrack your functionality to suit.
For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature[]" value="<?php  echo $row['ads_id']; ?>">
```

A check box value is set when the checkbox is checked, your code above will mean that the value of the feature checkbox will always be "feature" but it wont relate the the 'ads_id' field.

By changing to the example above you could then:

- update the table to say that none of the adds are featured
- loop through the feature[] form variable to update the table to set the featured column to true for the selected columns.

I have done a similar thing but used radiogroups because check's only give you a value if they are checked.

E.g:

```
  <label><input type="radio" name="feature[$id]" value="yes"/>yes</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="feature[$id]" value="no"/>no</label>
```

hth :)

Comment: I want that when I check a checkbox only that row will be mention as featureads.